# How to produce aluminium powder by E. J. Hall method

Tags: chemical-engineering, metallurgy, metals, aluminum

I have watched videos on YouTube producing Aluminum powder by mechanical methods. Like [this one](https://youtu.be/phMgqT6EsYc). It uses Aluminum foil and coffee grinder:

[image: Aluminum foil on YouTube video]

[image: Coffee grinder on YouTube video]

[image: Aluminum powder produced by coffee grinder]

There are [similar videos](https://youtu.be/s8_mo3at40M) which use the same basic method but with some sort of ball mill:

[image: Glass marbles as ball mill]

Is there any reference to produce Aluminum powder by any metallurgic (non-mechanical) method like [Everett Joel Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everett_Joel_Hall) method?

Comment: The link you provide us at the end has zero mention on how to produce Aluminium powder by non-mechanical process. Would you mind giving us a few more details?

Comment: @ComradeH Right. I'm researching to find more details on it. I just thought maybe someone can point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I just check it online, and the wiki link only briefly mentions Hall's method (but does not describe how). I suggest you try some other platform, Quora is always a good option.

Comment: @ComradeH Thanks =) I'm going to try Quora